Cannot post image as a form payload element to Node.js API
I am struggling very hard with Javascript under Node.js, which should read a file from disk and post it via  a post-request to DeepStack Facial Recognition system to do something with it.
I currently always receive a 400 Code --> "No valid image file found"
I think it might have to do with the file not being transported via Axios as the post-payload.
The following code I am using:
const fs = require("fs")
const axios = require("axios")
const FormData= require('form-data')

var image_stream = fs.createReadStream('./somefile.jpg')
var form = new FormData()
form.append('image', image_stream);
axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "http://192.168.178.46:666/v1/vision/face/recognize",
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
    data: form,
    timeout: 1000
}).then(function (response) {
   // do some stuff with the response
}).catch(function(error){log(error)})

Neither createReadStream nor ReadFileSync is working here and also everything I have tried with the header and the form-data was not working.
I also tried fetch and other packages to send the data, but no luck.
Can you help me here with advice?

The multi part request is probably not formed well, so, try:

omitting content-type header:

axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "http://192.168.178.46:666/v1/vision/face/recognize",
    data: form,
    timeout: 1000


or use FormData's method to set headers:

axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "http://192.168.178.46:666/v1/vision/face/recognize",
    headers: { ...form.getHeaders() },
    data: form,
    timeout: 1000 


Hi @traynor. Thanks for the answer.
I alread did play aroung with the headers, inherited them from the form and used different methods to read the file, combine it as form-data and used different libraries to send the post-request.
Is there a best practise how to send post-requests with multipart-form-data in node.js (not browsers)?

are you saying that neither of these two options worked...? did they give the same error..? also, which axios and node version are you using?

yes, that is right. If I use the form.headers, I get a timeout.
I use node v18.20.4 and Axios v1.7.2

try increasing timeout.. and what if you try with request: https://deepstacknodejs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/facerecognition.html#id1

After playing around a bit more and also increasing the timeout to allow the targeted server to process the load, I ended up with these two codes for my two use-case

add a local file as a payload
add a file from a url as a payload
The main confusion was/is about in exact type the response is received (stream, buffer, string) etc. and how to properly pass it to axios. It was even really cumbersome to get the right moment for the request to be made as the stream potentially was not read yet.
Parts of the confusion is and was because I am mostly always are used to code synchroneously which clashes with node.js main idea to be mostly asyncroneous.
Also, to provide a filename to an file-buffer provided as form-data seemed necessary.

Here is the code I ended up with:
Main code to handle the uniformed "file" payload:
const fs = require("fs")
const axios = require("axios")
const FormData= require('form-data')
var formData = new FormData()
formData.append('image', file, 'name.jpg')
    await axios({url: 'http://192.168.178.46:666/v1/vision/face/recognize',
        method: 'post',
        data: formData,
        headers: formData.getHeaders(),
        timeout: 60000
    }).then(async function (response) {
         // receive the proper response
    }).catch(function(error){log(error)})

The code to get the image payload from a local file (any Stream-related implementation failed):
var file= fs.readFileSync('./somelocalfile.jpg')
post_the_file_with_the_code_above(file)

The code to get an image payload from a url (was not possible to achieve with axios in my case:
const client = require('http');
var chunks = []
client.get('http://remote.url.com/image.jpg', (res) => {
     res.on('data', function(chunk) {
         chunks.push(Buffer.from(chunk))
     })
     res.on('end', async function () {
         var file= Buffer.concat(chunks)
         post_the_file_with_the_code_above(file)
     })
});

Thank you very much for your input though!
